# python: Dictionary Operation, KeyError: '0'

Tags: python, directory

I want to extract information from a text file and store the data in a directionary. The file records semicolon seperated values. That is, it records one property in one line, and the key and the value are seperated by a semicolon followed by a white space.

```
def info_file_parser(info_file):
  f=open(info_file,'rb')
  info={}
  for line in f:
    line=line.rstrip()
    mlist=line.split(": ")
    if len(mlist)==2:
      info[mlist[0]]=info[mlist[1]]

if __name__='__main__':
  fname="/Users/me/info.txt"
  info_file_parser(fname)
```

KeyError: '0'. What's wrong with that? Why can't I create keys by assignment?

Comment: I think it should be this `info[mlist[0]]=mlist[1]`

Comment: @VigneshKalai you are right. thank you. :)

Comment: `info[mlist[0]]=info[mlist[1]]`  the `info[mlist[1]` part tries to access and return mlist[1] key's value in info  dict, which doesn't exist

Comment: @dudu happy to help :) I think you can accept an answer which explained it clearly to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line:

```
info[mlist[0]]=info[mlist[1]]
```

tries to store value from info dictonary with key mlist[1] and try this:

```
info[mlist[0]]=mlist[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set a key in your dictionary with a key that doesn't exist.

In the `if` statement of your function, shouldn't it be:

```
if len(mlist)==2:
      info[mlist[0]]=mlist[1]
```